# REST API routes not displaying content as expected

Tags: javascript, api, rest, frontend, ejs

I am taking a javascript class where we are building a project and each week we are adding something new that builds on top of the previous week's work. This week we are supposed to use REST API's for the routes in our web application.
My routes aren't working as expected but I do not understand why.

My `app.get("/api/cars")` route is displaying the content in JSON format instead of it being rendered through my ejs template.

My `app.post("/api/cars")` is generating a server error and I don't know why.

All of my routes containing "/api/cars/:manufacturer" return 'Not Found'.

Here is my code, I have an index.js file:

```
"use stict";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import { Car } from "./models/Car.js";

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/api/cars", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const cars = await Car.find({});
    res.json(cars);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});
app.get("/api/cars/:manufacturer", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const car = await Car.findOne({ manufacturer: req.params.manufacturer });
    if (!car) {
      res.sendStatus(404);
    } else {
      res.json(car);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});
app.post("/api/cars", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const car = new Car(req.body);
    await car.save();
    res.sendStatus(201);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});
app.delete("/api/cars/:manufacturer", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await Car.deleteOne({
      manufacturer: req.params.manufacturer,
    });
    if (result.deletedCount === 0) {
      res.sendStatus(404);
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(204);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const cars = await Car.find({});
    res.render("home", { items: cars });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});

app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
  console.log("received request");
  res.type("about page");
  res.sendFile("/public/about.html");
});
app.get("/details/:manufacturer", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const car = await Car.findOne({ manufacturer: req.params.manufacturer });
    if (!car) {
      res.sendStatus(404);
    } else {
      res.render("details", { car });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.type("text/plain");
  res.status(404);
  res.send("404 - Not Found");
});

app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
  console.log("Express started");
});
```

And a Car.js file connecting to a really small MongoDB database that lists cars and some of their traits:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const { Schema } = mongoose;

import { connectionString } from "../credentials.js";

mongoose.connect(connectionString, {
  dbName: "Course-Projects",
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

mongoose.connection.on("open", () => {
  console.log("Mongoose connected.");
});

// define data model as JSON key/value pairs
// values indicate the data type of each key
const carSchema = new Schema({
  manufacturer: { type: String, required: true },
  model: String,
  horsepower: Number,
  trimModel: String,
});

export const Car = mongoose.model("Car", carSchema);
```

And the content is rendered using 2 ejs files, home.ejs and details.ejs.

Home.ejs:

```
<html>
    <Body>
        <h1>Cars I like</h1>
        <ul>
          <% items.forEach(car => { %>
            <li><a href="/details/<%= car.manufacturer %>"><%= car.manufacturer %> - <%= car.model %></a></li>
            <% }) %>
        </ul>
        
      </body>
</html>
```

Details.ejs:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Car details</h1>
    <p><a href="/">Back to home</a></p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Manufacturer</th>
        <td><%= car.manufacturer %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Model</th>
        <td><%= car.model %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Horsepower</th>
        <td><%= car.horsepower %>hp</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Trim model</th>
        <td><%= car.trimModel %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer your questions below.

1. The GET request for route /api/cars returns with `res.json(cars)`. Instead try to render the cars output using `res.render({your.object})`
2. The POST request for route /api/cars is probably returning an error because something is not working in the following code

   const car = new Car(req.body);
   await car.save();
3. The DELETE routes for /api/cars:manufacturer is probably returning 'Not found' because the res.sendStatus(404) is triggered. The 'car' object is empty after you `await Car.findOne(...`

I hope this helps you to learn more about ExpressJS, it's awesome!